# Permission denied for hive scratch directory while trying to establish connection using Hive streaming api

Tags: java, hadoop, permissions, hive, hdfs

I am writing a sample program using HCatalogue Streaming api

I have a running hadoop, Hiveserver and a Hivemetastore server.

I write a java program to connect to hive metastore.The source code is given below

```
public class HCatalogueStreamingclient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "E:\\midhun\\hadoop\\hive\\winutils");
        String dbName = "hive_streaming";
        String tblName = "alerts";
        ArrayList<String> partitionVals = new ArrayList<String>(2);
        partitionVals.add("Asia");
        partitionVals.add("India");
        HiveEndPoint hiveEP = new HiveEndPoint("thrift://192.168.10.149:8000", dbName, tblName, partitionVals);
        HiveConf conf = new HiveConf();
        conf.set("hive.exec.scratchdir", "/tmp/hivetmp");

        try {
            StreamingConnection connection = hiveEP.newConnection(true,conf);
        } catch (ConnectionError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidPartition e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidTable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (PartitionCreationFailed e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ImpersonationFailed e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

While running the program I am getting following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hivetmp on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:690)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:622)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:513)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$ConnectionImpl.createPartitionIfNotExists(HiveEndPoint.java:445)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$ConnectionImpl.<init>(HiveEndPoint.java:314)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$ConnectionImpl.<init>(HiveEndPoint.java:278)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint.newConnectionImpl(HiveEndPoint.java:215)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint.newConnection(HiveEndPoint.java:192)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint.newConnection(HiveEndPoint.java:113)
    at com.mj.HCatalogueStreamingclient.main(HCatalogueStreamingclient.java:27)
```

**Any one have an Idea on how to grand write permission to the hdfs folder /tmp/hivetmp**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is identified.

- We need to grand all permission for hadoop directory /tmp/hivetmp.The command      for granding permission is $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -chmod 777 -R /tmp/hivetmp
- I was running the program in Windows 7 64 bit OS.We need to download winutils appropriate to the operating system and version.

After doing above given points I was able to establish connection using Hive HCatalogue Streaming api